# Adding a custom field to do_shortcode

Tags: shortcode, advanced-custom-fields

I think this will be pretty easy to answer...My php knowledge isn't great!

I have used the Advanced Custom Fields plugin to create an 'add Slideshare shortcode' custom field in my page. The user would add shortcode generated from Slideshare enabling them to display their slideshare presentation, see below...

```
[slideshare id=7901921&doc=embed-slideshare-110509200429-phpapp01]
```

My issue is that I cannot add the call for the custom field to the "echo do_shortcode" command in my page.php. I have..

```
<?php   $slides = the_sub_field('slideshare');
                echo do_shortcode('" .$slides. "'); ?>
```

I know this is incorrect but don't know how to amend it. Any pointers would be gratefully met!

Answer (score 1):

There's a general convention in WordPress:

1. functions prefixed with `the_` will **echo** a value
2. functions prefixed with `get_` or `get_the_` will **return** a value

In your case you need to use `get_sub_field()` instead of `the_sub_field()` eg:

```
echo do_shortcode( get_sub_field( 'slideshare' ) );
```

The documentation on the ACF site is very comprehensive: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/get_sub_field/

**NOTE:** In your example code you didn't need any of the quotes, you could've just passed in the `$slides` variable directly if you were using `get_sub_field()`

Comment: Thanks, that didn't quite work but with a little tinkering I got it...

`$slides = get_sub_field('slideshare');
echo do_shortcode('" .$slides. "');`